# YOaf/MrA - What character encoding?

Tags: string, encryption, encoding, character

What kind of character encoding are the strings below?

```
KDLwuq6IC 
YOaf/MrAT
0vGzc3aBN 
SQdLlM8G7
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I understand your decition

Answer (score 0):

Character encoding is the encoding of strings to bytes (or numbers). You are only showing us the characters itself. They don't have any encoding by themselves.

Some character encodings have a different range of characters that they can encode. Your characters are all in the ASCII range at least. So they would also be compatible with any scheme that incorporates ASCII as a subset such as Windows-1252 and of course Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE etc).

Note that your code looks a lot like base 64. Base 64 is not a character encoding though, it is the encoding of bytes into characters (so the other way around). Base 64 can usually be recognized by looking for `/` and `+` characters in the text, as well as the text consisting of blocks that are a multiple of 4 characters (as 4 characters encode 3 bytes).

Looking at the text you are probably looking for an [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) scheme rather than a [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) scheme.

Comment: I only have those strings :( Can I decode them somehow?

Comment: Note that there are actually base 64 encodings out there where a different alphabet is used, equating some kind of simple substitution cipher. Those may be hard to decode.

Comment: Don't mind downvotes, but could the last person to downvote at least indicate why this is a bad answer?

Comment: You mean my strings provided is hard to decode or a general base64 string?

Comment: I did UP-VOTE your answer again... :)

Comment: This doesn't look like Base64 encoding, because there are 9 characters in each line, which is not a multiple of 4. If we would assume that padding characters are not shown, then this leaves the last character to carry less than 8 bits, which would be strange. (good answer, but bad question. I haven't downvoted. btw.)

Comment: Well, as decoded base 64 string it doesn't make too much sense to me, but without any indication what the output could look like this is just a guessing game. @ArtjomB. when I was answering the string was still concatenated :)

Comment: Ok, I dont understand everything, but I know there are IP-addresses behind the strings. Can that info help us? Or is it better to give up? Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Barely; IPv4 consists of 4 bytes that may have about any value. At least you know you can look at each line separately. You can try a few encodings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) (only those with high efficiency) and hope for the best.